# jmeter regular expression extracting specific

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract : children from "name":"recordInstanceId" from the following JSON.

The output should give me "lQBfjAu....P0tk" . How do I do it using Regex Extractor?

```
{
      "name":"recordTypeView",
      "attributes":{
       "xmlns":""
      },
      "children":["all"
      ]
     },{
      "name":"isRuleBacked",
      "attributes":{
       "xmlns":""
      },
      "children":["false"
      ]
     },{
      "name":"recordInstanceId",
      "attributes":{
       "xmlns":""
      },
      "children":["lQBfjAu....P0tk"
      ]
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract `lQBfjAu....P0tk` from the following response:

```
{
    "name": "recordInstanceId",
        "attributes": {
    "xmlns": ""
},
    "children": [
    "lQBfjAu....P0tk"
    ]
}
```

It could be done with [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) (available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasWithLibsSet/)) with a simple JSON Path Expression like:

```
$..children[0]
```

It isn't recommended to use Regular Expressions for dealing with JSON data, I would recommend extracting data from JSON responses with the JSON Path Extractor.

References:

- [JSON Path Syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2)
- [Plugin installation instructions and XPath to JSON Path mapping](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

If you have any troubles - update your question to show complete response

Comment: I need a child that has "name":"recordInstanceId", I tried $..children[0], its not picking the right one with json extractor

Comment: Cause there are 3 JSON Objects in your response snippet. I have already suggested posting the full server's response.

Comment: {
 "feed":{
  "title":"",
  "links":[{
    "href":"https://host/view/summary",
    "rel":"entry-detail",
    "extensions":[{
      "name":"available",
      "attributes":{
       "xmlns":""
      },
      "children":["true"
      ]
     },{
      "name":"recordTypeView",
      "attributes":{
       "xmlns":""
      },
      "children":["all"
      ]
     },
      "children":["false"
      ]
     },{
      "name":"recordInstanceId",
      "attributes":{
       "xmlns":""
      },
      "children":["lMBfjA...aMd8Oabg"
      ]
     },
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}

Comment: Other response has the recordinstandId as first children..       feed":{
  "title":"",
  "links":[{
    "href":"#",
    "rel":"entry-detail",
    "extensions":[{
      "name":"available",
      "attributes":{
       "xmlns":""
      },
      "children":["false"
      ]
     },{
      "name":"recordInstanceId",
      "attributes":{
       "xmlns":""
      },
      "children":["lQBfjAu6..7u8L94MI4c-t0cfhZIrMRX3o"
      ]

Comment: None of them is a valid JSON, apologies, I cannot help this way